# OpenGLES20 View is distorted with rotation matrix applied

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

Video of how it's looking right now:

http://de.tinypic.com/r/2504bh5/8

I am applying a rotation matrix to my view matrix:

```
    float[] mTmpMatrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mTmpMatrix, 0, // mViewMatrix
            mCameraPosition[0], mCameraPosition[1], mCameraPosition[2], // eye
            mTargetRotPosition[0], mTargetRotPosition[1], mTargetRotPosition[2],
            0, 1, 0); // up
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mTmpMatrix, 0);
```

To let the OpenGL view rotate respective to the device's orientation to create some sort of augmented reality. The rotation matrix is calculated from sensor fusion (Magnetic, Accelerometer, Gyroscope) and is working quite well.

The problem I'm having right now is the following: The screen, better yet the objects I'm drawing, are distorted if I rotate my device, which should be a rotation along the Z axis.

The following images should give some sort of impression of what I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

This is when looking "up", at the ceiling of the rectangle I've drawn around the camera. The roof suddenly becomes a square, to still fit on the screen, but I don't know why and how I can prevent this from happening, since if I, instead of rotating the view matrix, would rotate the lines, this should not happen.

For completion's sake, the Line.class:

http://pastebin.com/GQszFEPm

Frustum settings (FoV for testing purposes, I did some experiments with this value, but no effects)

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    if (height > width)
        setFrustumVertical(100f, (float) height / (float) width, 0.01f, 11f);
    else setFrustumHorizontal(100f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.01f, 11f);
}
```

The helper methods, I've adapted from a tutorial:

```
private void setFrustumHorizontal(float fov, float aspect, float front, float back) {
    fov = (float) Math.toRadians(fov);                      // transform fov from degrees to radians
    fov = 2.0f * (float) Math.atan(Math.tan(fov * 0.5f) / aspect);  // transform from horizontal fov to vertical fov

    float tangent = (float) Math.tan(fov / 2.0f);               // tangent of half vertical fov
    float height = front * tangent;                 // half height of near plane
    float width = height * aspect;                  // half width of near plane

    setFrustum(-width, width, -height, height, front, back);
}

private void setFrustumVertical(float fov, float aspect, float front, float back) {
    fov = (float) Math.toRadians(fov);                      // transform fov from degrees to radians

    float tangent = (float) Math.tan(fov / 2.0f);               // tangent of half vertical fov
    float height = front * tangent;                 // half height of near plane
    float width = height * aspect;                  // half width of near plane

    setFrustum(-width, width, -height, height, front, back);
}

private void setFrustum(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far) {
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you set up your projection matrix? Disortion can occur if it does not correctly represent the geometry of the screen.

Comment: @NigelK I've added how I'm calculating the frustum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an issue with setFrustumVertical(). Let us assume your screen is 100 x 200 and in portrait (so twice as high as it is wide). Since height > width you will call:

```
setFrustumVertical(100f, 2, 0.01f, 11f)
```

If you dry run that method using those values (I've used degrees here rather than radians but the maths is the same):

```
fov = 100 degrees
tangent = tan(100 / 2) = 1.191
height = 0.01 x 1.191 = 0.01191
width = 0.01191 x 2 = 0.02382
setFrustrum(-0.02382, 0.02382, -0.01191, 0.01191, 0.01, 11)
```

Notice how the frustrum is twice as wide as it is tall? That's back to front - it should be twice as high as it is wide in portrait. Switch width and height around:

```
float width = front * tangent;
float height = height * aspect;
```

Or perhaps width should instead be set with:

```
float width = height / aspect;
```

If you get a similar issue in landscape, dry run the other method by hand as well to ensure it creates a frustrum with the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: Looks like this solved the problem! Thank you very much. This just saved me from another couple of days looking elsewhere for the problem. I'll make a "dry run" for the horizontal method as well.

Answer (score 2):

Set the mViewMatrix to identity before the line you are setting it as mRotationMatrix*mTmpMatrix.

Comment: Did not change the distortion, unfortunately

Comment: Well i see that you are applying a rotation matrix by premultiplying it with the View matrix.Try not to do this.Instead apply the rotation matrix by post multiplying it with mVP matrix at last(just before drawing).Tell me what happens then

Comment: If I switch the multiplication's order, the distortion is still existent - the angles in the rectangle are not even 90° anymore, and also the camera's movements, i.e the basic rotation doesn't really work anymore.

Comment: I also tried to pre/post multiply the rotation matrix with the MVP matrix of the Line-objects I'm drawing. Post-multiplication has the same effect, i.e. the rectangle becomes some sort of a square.. pre-multiplication too, but also the lines somehow disappeared half

Comment: Why are you applying rotation about x and y in your draw method if the rotation about any axis was to be taken care here

Comment: Well, the MVP matrix is for a specific model/object, right? So where else should I apply it to the MVP matrix? Or did you mean the VP matrix

Comment: Brother i think the rotation matrix may be the culprit here...and as u know rotation matrix rotates stuff around 0,0,0..i hope you are taking care of that as you want rotation about the camera pos

Comment: Also since you are drawing all the elements in one draw command,your model rotation is getting applied to the whole view...try disabling the model rotation for once and tell me if the distortion persists  i.e delete this for a moment..   Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

Answer (score 2):

Your error is likely here:

```
setFrustumVertical(100f, height / width, 0.01f, 11f);
```

Because height and width are integers, and height > width (&& height < 2 * width) the result will always be 1. Try casting them to float *before* the division:

```
setFrustumVertical(100f, (float)height / (float)width, 0.01f, 11f);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I changed it, but it did not change the distortion.